# Difference between something like 先週は... and 私は先週

Tags: grammar

For example, if I'm talking about something I did last week, is there a difference in these two examples, or are they the same thing. For example, if I plug in 本を読みました, or something like that into the ....
ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

As far as it is your own action, they are virtually the same.

- 先週は本を読みました

has the implicit *I*, so that it is equivalent to

- 先週は私は本を読みました

which is more or less equivalent to

- 私は先週は本を読みました

In all of the above, 先週は can be just 先週. The difference in these particular sentences is that using 先週は (and particularly the first one) sounds like the は being contrastive, so that something like *but this week...* is expected implicitly (or later in the sentence).